# How to remove geo location event as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, geolocation, actionscript-2

With gpson_btn I need to  remove geo updates...

```
gpsoff_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, geoON);
function geoON(event: Event): void {
if (Geolocation.isSupported) {
    var geo = new Geolocation();
    geo.setRequestedUpdateInterval(1);
    geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, geolocationUpdateHandler);
    gpsoff_btn.visible = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution!

```
gpson_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, geoOFF);
function geoOFF(event: Event): void {
geo.removeEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, geolocationUpdateHandler);
```